# Preserve number of solutions when transforming equation over GF(n)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I'm trying to understand a proof in my textbook, which is about uniformity of functions over finite fields (GF(2^n)).
It's about finding the maximum number of solutions for an equation containing a certain function f(x) over GF(2^n).

Consider $c,d \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and $f: \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \mapsto \mathbb{F}_{2^n} | f(x) = x^{-1}$

It starts with the equation:

$x^{-1} + (x+c)^{-1} = d$

for which the number of solutions for any given c and d is needed. After some transforming we have:

$\frac{c}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{c}+1} = c*d$

So far so good, but now, the authors just substitute:

$cd = d$ and $\frac{x}{c}=x$

While I can still understand the first one (since you also could rewrite it as something like $cd = e$, because e [or that 'new' d] is just a permutation of the domain $F_{2^n}$), the latter beats me.
How may I know I don't change the number of solutions to that equation, when I effectively set $c=1$?

Another proof does an equal trick. It has:

$a^d\left(\left(\frac{x}{a}+1\right)^d + \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^d  \right) = b$
, with a and b as constants of $F_{2^n}$
and then it states, that the following has the same number of solutions for x:

$(x+1)^d + (x)^d = \frac{b}{a^d}$

and later even:

$(x+1)^d + (x)^d = b$

Again, they seem to just liquidate $\frac{x}{a}$ and I just don't get why this is possible.

UPDATE:
The first proof ends in this:

$dx^2 + dx + 1 = 0$

In the next step it's suddenly just:

$x^2 + x + 1 = 0$, which is quietly assumed to have same number of solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. Just because it's a quadratic equation, I can leave out every parameter? Next step, after multiplying with $x(x+1):\\$
$x^4+x=0$

which would look different, if we hadn't just removed the 'd's.

Comment: As long as $c \neq 0$, they just solve $\displaystyle\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{y+1}=b(=cd)$ for $y=\displaystyle\frac{x}{c}$.

Comment: So you mean $\frac{x}{c}=x$ is actually 'a different x' and thus could also be $\frac{x}{c}=y$ as you wrote?

Comment: Yes. The number of solutions stays the same (for the very reason you note).

Comment: APN-functions/sequences?

Comment: @metamorphy: do you have a hint for the last eq, the one with the d's, too?

Comment: The number of solutions of $x^2+x+1=0$ depends on $tr(1)=n\cdot1$. If $n$ is even, there are two solutions. If $n$ is odd there are none. Similarly with $dx^2+dx+1=0$, which is equivalent to $x^2+x+(1/d)=0$. If $tr(1/d)=0$ then it has two solutions, but if $tr(1/d)=1$ then there are no solutions in $GF(2^n)$. In other words, the number of solutions depends on $d$, and is definitely not the same for all values of $d$. If it were $d^2x^2+dx+1=0$ instead, then it would be the same. The substitution $y=dx$.

Comment: @Jyrki: what is this tr() in that context?

Comment: Andreas, it's the trace function: $tr: GF(2^n)\to GF(2)$. Defined as
$$tr(x)=x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\cdots+x^{2^{n-1}}.$$ Its basic properties are
A) $tr(x+y)=tr(x)+tr(y)$ for all $x,y\in GF(2^n)$, B) $tr(x^2)=tr(x)$ for all $x\in GF(2^n)$, and C) $x^2+x=a$ has solutions $x\in GF(2^n)$ if and only if $tr(a)=0$.